# Name PC during Windows 10 installation?

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

I recently formatted my hard disk and did a clean installation of Windows 10. One thing I noticed was that the installer doesn't ask for PC name anymore as it did in previous version. It automatically assigns a random PC name (my laptop has been given DESKTOP-XXXXXXX, which is quite annoying).

Why does Windows 10 do this? Is there any way to specify PC name during installation?

I think PC name must be referenced many times in registry and elsewhere, so it is not a good idea to change it. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: "...it is not a good idea to change it. Correct me if I am wrong." Renaming the computer after installation has no ill effects.

Comment: As far as I know renaming computer names via a proper interface (e.g. control panel - system or right click on 'my computer' on the desktop and select properties never cause any problems. Not sure what happens if you try a registry hack, but renaming even domain joined PCs just works and never gave me or my coworkers any problems.

Comment: As to why: I *guess* it is one less confusing question for most users. And it prevent those users from trying to call all PCs the same (e.g. all 'myPC', 'Jansen', 'Smith', 'desktop' etc etc).

Answer (score 2):

On the "How would you like to setup?" page Press **Shift F10** to open a command prompt.

At the command prompt type **sysdm.cpl** to open the System Properties page

Click on the **Change Button**, Rename the computer, Click **OK** several times,

Click **Close** on the system properties window

Click **Restart Now**

Windows setup should launch again, continue setup as normal

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post a reply here, even though this is a very old topic.  I ran into a situation recently that I have never run into before and I haven't found the solution documented anywhere else.

I had a computer that was not connecting to the ethernet network.  It was getting an IP address via DHCP, running ipconfig /all showed the correct gateway/router, I tried multiple cables.  That's about all of the troubleshooting help I got from Google searches.  Either it was a bad cable or DHCP wasn't working.

After looking just about everywhere else, just taking stabs at looking at settings, I stumbled upon computer name.  The router was showing that an IP address was given to a device, but the device name was blank.  I checked Windows settings and sure enough this computer didn't have a name.  Now I"m not sure if that was an error during setup or something.  As the original poster said, Windows just assigns a computer name, like "Desktop-1X2Y3Z".  But this computer had no name.  I added a name, restarted and it connected to the network.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).